# javascript for re-directing local file

Tags: javascript, html, windows, browser, smb

I am attempting to put together a short script that I want to place on a Google "Site"
page. What I want to do is select a file that is local to my browser and then
re-direct it to a folder on a local windows server. I have been playing with file
upload and then download but essentially getting nowhere. HTML 5 has a "Download"
tag but Sites appears to disallow it for some reason.

We use a mix of browsers here:IE(8-10),FF,Chrome.

I have seen many good solutions but they all seem to need server side code. Which I cannot
do.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I suspect that the uploaded file is either an document entity or element that I can then save. This is as far as I have gotten.

Comment: It would be nice if I could do a "<output type="file:...>

Comment: Further investigation indicates that an href might work but not with the way the file server is currently set up. (windows/domain/smb) The easiest path looks like an FTP link.